# Does R Chi-Square test consider the order of a ordered factor?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I would like to test if there is an association between:

-A binary factor: 0, 1 (recovered vs not recovered)
-A ordered factor: Iron level 1, 2, 3 (low, medium, high)

I was wondering if the rank of the iron level variables is considered, when testing for an association between those two variables using a Chi-Square test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.  1, 2, 3 are treated pretty much like unordered labels like "red", "green", "blue".

Comment: Thank you! Argh, I was worried it wouldn't, as the p-value is exactly the same when I tested the iron level as nominal factor. Do you  have advice about which test I could use to test the association between an ordered factor and a binary categorical variable as in the example above?

Comment: A chi-square test surely is an option (would work even if the variable is ordered).  You could treat the ordinal values as continuous and do the t-test to see if the mean is different between recovered vs not-recovered.  Of course, this isn't really treating this variable as ordinal though.  And this is a deep area.  Have a look like this https://www.researchgate.net/post/Which_statistical_test_is_used_for_categorical_ordinal_variable

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. I think I'll take your advice and do a t-test to see if there is a significant difference in the means.